# How would you find the min/max of a continuous, nowhere differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis

A continuous function attains its min and mix over a closed set. So let's suppose there is a continuous, nowhere differentiable function over the set $[a,b],$ like a Weierstrass function. Since we can't use calculus, how could we find its min/max?

Comment: You might be interested in the paper "EXTREMA AND NOWHERE DIFFERENTIABLE FUNCTIONS," E.E. POSEY AND J.E. VAUGHAN, ROCKY MOUNTAIN JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS, Volume 16, Number 4, Fall 1986.

Comment: This seems to suggest that the max or min is dense. But I have a hard time believing that must always be true for all no-where differentiable continuous functions because there's so many ways the function could fluctuate. Couldn't the min or max just by one infinitessimal spike that is never attained again over a closed domain? Why must the max/min be dense?